# Is there any library in any language that have tools to work with wireless measurements?

Tags: arduino, rssi, zigbee, xbee

I want some library to guide my implementation with zigbee wireless received strength signal RSS. Any standard or class code will help. I focusing in arduino platform (xbee modules).

Comment: FYI, the RSS tag refers to "Really Simple Syndication" or "RDF Site Summary", not Received Signal Strength (as it might on the EE stack exchange).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Arduino library for communicating with ZigBee/XBee: [xbee-arduino](http://code.google.com/p/xbee-arduino/)

Comment: I know about xbee. RSSI measurements are treated as a unsigned byte there. What I want to know is if some library implementing a way to treat it outside the xbee or if have some library-methods to use with this measurements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but hopefully a pointer to where you'll find an answer. The XBee Series 2 uses a Ember EM250 ZigBee/802.15.4 transceiver chip. The RSSI value from the XBee module is very likely to be the value returned from that transceiver chip. The chip data sheet is here: http://www.ember.com/pdf/120-0082-000_EM250_Datasheet.pdf
Doing a search on Ember's website for "RSSI" and "LQI" also throws up other documents which might help.

Answer (score 0):

A received strength signal indicator is in arbitrary units, and is basically only useful as a relative measure for comparing identical hardware.

> In an IEEE 802.11 system RSSI is the relative received signal strength in a wireless environment, in arbitrary units.[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication)

It's may be useful as a debug tool by developers, but is usually not useful for the application code itself. I can't imagine a library would be useful here. What exactly would you want a library to do with this value?

Answer (score 0):

According to the XBee manual, RSSI is measured in dBm (decibels referenced by milliwatt). To my knowledge there are no RSSI-specific libraries or methods.